# Airflow installation failure beam[gcp]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, apache-beam

Airflow installation with command is failing

```
sudo pip3 install apache-airflow[gcp_api]
```

Everything was working fine  yesterday. Today I see the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-beam[gcp]==2.3.0 (from google-cloud-dataflow->apache-airflow[gcp_api]) (from versions: 0.6.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0)
No matching distribution found for apache-beam[gcp]==2.3.0 (from google-cloud-dataflow->apache-airflow[gcp_api])
```

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I faced the same problem :(

**Why?**
most likely it happened because in the new version(2.3.0) of apache-beam they actually added the restriction for python3
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apache-beam/2.3.0
`Requires Python: >=2.7,<3.0`
the previous packages didn't have this restriction, that is why it was working before(if you didn't use dataflow from gcp).

- probably you have the last version of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-dataflow/2.3.0 which has updated apache-beam package

**How to fix?**

uninstall google-cloud-dataflow

```
pip3 uninstall google-cloud-dataflow
```

and install version 2.2.0 which has the old version of apache beam

```
pip install google-cloud-dataflow==2.2.0
```

Fixed this problem for me, I hope it will help you as well

Comment: i figured from your answer that if I install airflow with python 2.7 everything gets install as it needs to be. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MohammedTameem not necessary, I'm using python3 and had the same problem, downgrading version of `google-cloud-dataflow` helped me

Comment: Ok... Thanks for the info @Nick

Comment: @NickBilozerov I'm in python3 and `apache-beam`(2.2.0) is giving me trouble. `grcpi` dependency specifically.

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved in the master branch at Apache Airflow Github by [Pull Request #3273](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3273) .

You can install the latest development branch using the below commands.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow
pip install git+https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow#egg=apache-airflow[gcp_api]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix! For my future reference the Jira issue associated with that PR is https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2266